# Robustness of largest singular vectors with respect to noise

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-theory, data-analysis

I would like to find a result that shows that the largest right-singular vectors of a data matrix are in some sense robust with respect to low-variance noise perturbations. Specifically, let $X = U D V^{\top}$ be the design matrix (each row $X_i$ is a data point). Now consider $\tilde{X}_i$ with $\tilde{X}_i := X_i + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I\sigma^2)$, i.i.d., for small $\sigma^2$. I could find plenty of literature which approximates the first few columns of $V$ by the first few columns of $\tilde{V}$ (e.g. this is what we do when using the PCA components of our data matrix to approximate the singular vectors of the true covariance matrix), yet none of these works I found seem to provide with theoretical results on why this is reasonable. I also see a link of my problem to approximating the factors in a linear factor analysis by the principal components of the data, but I get the same problem here.